# Vision framework on IOS for complex image recognition text

Tags: ios, frameworks, vision

I am new to vision framework.

I am trying to get text out from a complex image (like noisy images). I have done a basic code that prints on the console the extracted text. I cannot get the text out of complex ones. I can read simple document images, but not complex one, like for example:

[complex image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Db9ZN.jpg)

Instead i can get the text wih no problem of the following image:

[simple text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j6sS1.png)

Any suggestions on how to extract the code from the complex image?

This is what i've done so far:

```
import UIKit
import Vision

class ViewController: UIViewController {
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let image = UIImage(named: "example")
        
       
        if let cgImage = image?.cgImage {
          let requestHandler = VNImageRequestHandler(cgImage: cgImage)

          let recognizeTextRequest = VNRecognizeTextRequest { (request, error) in
            
            guard let observations = request.results as? [VNRecognizedTextObservation] else {
              return
            }
              
              
            let recognizedStrings = observations.compactMap { observation in
              observation.topCandidates(1)[0]
            }
            
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
              print(recognizedStrings)
            }
          }
          
            recognizeTextRequest.recognitionLevel = .accurate
          
          DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInitiated).async {
            do {
              try requestHandler.perform([recognizeTextRequest])
            } catch {
              print(error)
            }
          }
        }
    }
}
```

And this is the console result:

[console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pdJKB.png)